# Как поставить на img эффект tooltip . wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, img

Как поставить эффект tooltip js на img , проект на wordpress. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пример можете увидет на  этом сайте(moreair.co)

Comment: В теме есть moreairweb файл http://moreair.co/macms/wp-content/themes/moreairweb/js/lib.js, в нём js-код.

Comment: как найти именно этот код?

Comment: Картинка обернута в <a>. На <a> стоит Event Listeners mouseover на функцию save() в lib.js (строка 660). Так ищут код.

Comment: добавить этот файл на сайте и оно сработает или еще прописать что то на индексной странице?

Comment: Если бы у меня было время на полный ответ, я бы его сюда написал. Пока что я вам только показал путь, по которому надо идти, чтобы разобраться в том, как это устроено.

Comment: если бы помогли решить эту задачу , без благодоарности не оставил